# create two pdfs from one .ps file?

Tags: pdf, postscript

I need to reformat a text file into a PDF. Using Perl, I am modifying an existing PostScript template file based on what is in the text file. Sometimes this text file will be long enough to require a two page PDF.

Can I create a two page PDF file from one .ps file using GhostScript? If so, what tells GhostScript where the page break should occur?

Maybe I need to use two template files. One for a one page pdf and another for a two page PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostScript doesn't directly have the concept of text flows or page breaks.  The [showpage](http://www.tailrecursive.org/postscript/operators.html) operator renders the page to the device, clears the page and starts a new one.  PS to PDF conversion will create a new page in the PDF on this operator.  If you want to chop up a PostScript file into pages, [psutils](http://gershwin.ens.fr/vdaniel/Doc-Locale/Outils-Gnu-Linux/PsUtils/) is a series of programs for manipulating PostScript files.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it depends on what's in your PostScript template. A PostScript file is a computer program, and page breaks are determined by the logic in the PostScript. If the two-page format is substantially the same as the one-page format, you could have your Perl script split the data up, then create two single-page files concatenated together. GhostScript should render that file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's down to whatever is converting your text file to create appropriate PostScript commands to handle the page break.

A page break will happen if (and only if) your PostScript template invokes `showpage`.

Comment: This is true only for ps level 1; level 2 introduced (and level 3 deprecated) the copypage operator, which is like showpage, except it keeps the same page contents, which can then be added to.  Cf. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/postscript/pdfs/TN5608.Copypage.pdf

Comment: @CharlesStewart `copypage` was present in Level-1 interpreters and the PLRM 1ed.