# Is there a way to create Bookmarks for pdf documents in PDFBOX?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am currently generating a large document from a database scheme and especially in bigger databases the amount of pages quickly exceeds 1000 pages... I use PDFBox to create the document and I am wondering whether PDFBox supports any way of creating Bookmarks that are displayed in the left side of Acrobat when viewing the document.

On the website (and the related documentation) I haven't found anything helpful so far...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cf. the PDFBox example [CreateBookmarks.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateBookmarks.java).

Comment: See also [this answer in the mailing list from yesterday](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201407.mbox/%3C4BC07BF8-7DD9-4888-AA2B-0CF80DC88196%40fileaffairs.de%3E)

Comment: refer this one - [Watermarking with PDFBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929954/watermarking-with-pdfbox)