# PDFBox 2.0.27: Watermarking with map for page specific overlay files results in no watermark

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, watermark

**Background information**

I am using [PDFBox 2.0.27](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.27/index.html) and try to add watermarks on my PDF (may) containing multiple pages of different [Din formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size) and orientations (vertical & horizontal).

For this reason I created for each combination of Din format and orientation a PDF file, which I want to utilize for watermarks of the respective pages of my original PDF.

**Approach**

The specific page and overlay/watermark file relation is stored in `HashMap<Integer, String> overlayGuide = new HashMap<>();`

For adding watermarks to each page I use the following code:

```
PDDocument originalPDF = PDDocument.load(new File("..Original_PDF.pdf"));   // To adjust with actual path

HashMap<Integer, String> overlayGuide = new HashMap<>();
overlayGuide.put(1, "..A1_Horizontal_Watermark.pdf");   // To adjust with actual path

Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
overlay.setInputPDF(originalPDF);
overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);
originalPDF = overlay.overlay(overlayGuide);

originalPDF.save(new File("C:\\AxaviaPdfServiceAPI\\temp\\watermarked.pdf"));

overlay.close();
```

**Source of code snippet**

This code is based on the suggested code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929954/watermarking-with-pdfbox).

**Problem**

The watermarking doesn't work. The output generated by the above code is the original PDF. I receive no exceptions or errors or other hints I could deliver.

What am I missing? The method `overlay.setOutputFile("final.pdf");` as posted in the linked stackoverflow question is not available in my currently used version of PDFBox.

Size and orientation of page from original PDF and watermark PDF is (/should be) the same. Manual adding of watermark via Adobe Acrobat DC is working.

**Expected result**

Based on manual adding via Adobe Acrobat DC I expected something like [here](https://github.com/SeeAZO/stackoverflow_questions/blob/main/PDFBox_2.0.27_Watermark/res/Expected_Result_PDF.pdf)

Unfortunatelly I couldn't find an option in `Overlay` class to set **opacity** for the watermark PDF to add.

**What I tried**

See code snippet above & googeling, which resulted in more or less the same code snippet. Other solutions only handled simple text as watermark or images.

**Example files**

Example files to test my code can be found [here](https://github.com/SeeAZO/stackoverflow_questions/tree/main/PDFBox_2.0.27_Watermark/res)

**Boundary conditions**

I want to stick at template PDFs for watermarking, since I want to add additional icons/pictures. The provided example file is just a short draft.

---

**Update 2022-11-06**

> Please share both the input and the output PDFs of your test. –
> mkl

Original PDF: [here](https://github.com/SeeAZO/stackoverflow_questions/blob/main/PDFBox_2.0.27_Watermark/res/Original_PDF.pdf)

Watermark PDF: [here](https://github.com/SeeAZO/stackoverflow_questions/blob/main/PDFBox_2.0.27_Watermark/res/A1_Horizontal_Watermark.pdf)

Result PDF: [here](https://github.com/SeeAZO/stackoverflow_questions/blob/main/PDFBox_2.0.27_Watermark/res/watermarked.pdf)

---

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share both the input and the output PDFs of your test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question and linked your requested files

Comment: Ok, Original_PDF.pdf and watermarked.pdf represent the identical PDF. This essentially is a known bug, [PDFBOX-5523](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5523), that already has been fixed. That fix will be contained in 2.0.28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) for pointing out, that the approach with `HashMap<Integer, String> overlayGuide = new HashMap<>();` is currently bugged.

**Solution/Work-around**

I used the method `overlay.overlayDocuments(overlayGuidePDDocuments);` with `overlayGuidePDDocuments = HashMap<Integer, PDDocument>` and the watermarks are now set correctly.

**Remarks**

Setting an opacity for the watermark template PDFs is not possible (or I don't get it how to apply). Therefore the watermark template PDFs are prepared with an opacity.