# Inject PostScript code before 'showpage'

Tags: printing, postscript

I want to print a book on a laser printer, so I have prepared a PostScript file ready for printing, with reordered and 2-up'ed pages. Now I want to add booklet marks on appropriate pages, like on the following picture:

[image: Booklet marks]

From other SO questions I know that its `showpage` command that separates individual pages in PS file, so I wrote simple Perl script which counts `showpage`'s occurences and prepends PostSript code if necessary, just to test if this approach works:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bookletSheets = 6;

my $occurence = 1;
while (my $line = <>) {
    if ($line !~ /^showpage/) {
        print $line;
        next;
    }

    my $mod = $occurence % (2*$bookletSheets);
    if ($mod == 1) {
        print " 1    setlinewidth\n";
        print " 5  5 newpath moveto\n";
        print "-5  5 lineto\n";
        print "-5 -5 lineto\n";
        print " 5 -5 lineto\n";
        print " 5  5 lineto\n";
        print "0 setgray\n";
        print "stroke\n";
        print "%NOP\n"
    }

    print $line;
    $occurence++;
}
```

But after running:

```
$ cat book.ps | ./preprocess.pl > book-marked.ps
```

I can see no signs of additional marks in document viewer, despite the code got injected correctly. What have I done wrong?

There are some links I've based my thinking on:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/532220/1447225
- http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.lang.postscript/2007-11/msg00097.html
- http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks//graphics/howtops1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation, it turned out that the lack of image was caused by `BoundingBox` clipping. Bounding box was shifted because the PS file was obtained from PDF with stripped margins.

Comment: +1 glad you solved it. Another gotcha that I was about to post as a possible answer is the current transformation matrix. You might want to add `defaultmatrix setmatrix` at the front of your injected code to make sure your coordinates and size numbers are being interpreted at the correct position and scale..

Comment: @luserdroog: in fact I didn't solved the whole task yet, as it turns out that `pdf2ps` and `psnup` do extremely weird things with PostScript code. It seems that the only reliable approach is to override `showpage` in PostScript itself, avoiding text-level manipulation entirely.